# Error with Knockout-validation validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a collection of text editors in a form, validating them with knockout-validation.  When I submit the form, only a few of them show validation errors, although all of them should pass.  This issue only occurs with these two fields shown in error, however I have checked and double checked and all of the wiring for all of these is set up correctly, e.g. there is no reason I can see that these two fields should be different from the others that do not exhibit this issue.

I'm hoping that someone with more experience than I in the internals of knockout-validation could point me to something that may be alternately tripping the validation of these.  I have it set up to validate the text when a user clicks outside of the editor, and that works fine.  The issue below only appears when a user clicks submit, and other fields on the page (besides the editors shown here) have an issue. In other words, if every single field is valid, the form is submitted.  If any fields OTHER than those shown below have issues, the false positive is shown.

[image]

Adding Code examples:
Creating the validator and extending the observables.  Note the ones depicted in the image are configured identically to those not being marked invalid:

```
ko.validation.rules['notIn'] = {
    validator: function (value, params) {
        var thisValidator = baseCompare.slice();
        if (Array.isArray(params))
            params.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
                thisValidator.push(element);
            });
        else
            thisValidator.push(params);
        return thisValidator.indexOf(value) == -1;
    },
    message: 'Please enter a unique value'
};

ko.validation.registerExtenders();
self.setupValidation = function () {
    self.title.extend({
        required: true,
        notIn: {
            message: 'Please enter a unique title',
            params: self.froalaBasify('New Change Request')
        }
    });
    self.domain.extend({ required: true, notEqual: '0' }).extend({ notify: 'always' });
    self.priority.extend({ required: true, notEqual: '0' }).extend({ notify: 'always' });
    self.securityClassification.extend({ required: true, notEqual: '0' }).extend({ notify: 'always' });
    self.impact.extend({ required: true, notEqual: '0' }).extend({ notify: 'always' });
    self.customersAffected.extend({
        required: true,
        notIn: {
            message: 'Please describe the customers affected',
            params: self.froalaBasify(CRHelper.ValidationPlaceholders.customersAffected)
        }
    });
//False Positive
    self.justification.extend({
        required: true,
        notIn: {
            message: 'Please provide a justification for the request',
            params: self.froalaBasify(CRHelper.ValidationPlaceholders.justification)
        }
    });

    self.scope.extend({
        required: true,
        notIn: {
            message: 'Please describe the systems affected by this change',
            params: self.froalaBasify(CRHelper.ValidationPlaceholders.scope)
        }
    });
//False Positive
    self.validationProcess.extend({
        required: true,
        notIn: {
            message: 'Please enter a validation plan for this change',
            params: self.froalaBasify(CRHelper.ValidationPlaceholders.validationProcess)
        }
    });
    self.description.extend({
        required: true,
        notIn: {
            message: 'Please enter a description',
            params: self.froalaBasify(CRHelper.ValidationPlaceholders.description)
        }
    });
    self.deadlineRequested.extend({
        required: true,
        dateGreaterThanToday: {
            onlyIf: function () {
                //var isTrue = $('#ddTransition option:selected').text() == "Delete Request";
                //return !(isTrue);
                return self.id === 0;
            }
        }
    });
    //self.deadlineRequested.extend({
    //    required: true}).extend({ notify: 'always' });

};
```

And then here is the submit handler:

```
self.submitChangeRequest = function () {
    var validated = ko.validatedObservable(self.ChangeRequest());
    var transition = "";
    transition = $('#ddTransition option:selected').text();

    var disableValidation = false;
    if (transition == "Delete Request")
        disableValidation = true;
    var formIsValid = validated.isValid();
    if (CRHelper.ConfirmSubmitIfDeleteChosen() && (disableValidation || formIsValid)) {
        $('.submitter').prop('disabled', true);
        var formUsage = $("[id*='hdnFormUsage']")[0].value;
        var ajax = new utils.AjaxFormatter(
            {
                type: "POST",
                data: ko.toJSON(self.ChangeRequest()),
                url: DomainUtil.baseUrl + "api/ChangeRequests/",
                contentType: "application/json",
                headers: { 'formUsage': formUsage }
            },
            function (updatedModel, status, request) {
                var updateMessage = formUsage == 'execute' ? 'executed' : (formUsage == 'new' ? 'saved new' : transition == 'Delete Request' ? 'deleted' : 'updated');
                var $msg = $("[id*='StatusMessage']");
                $msg.html('Successfully ' + updateMessage + ' Change Request ' + updatedModel.id);
                $msg.addClass('alertGo').show().fadeOut({ duration: 8000, easing: 'easeInQuint', complete: function () { $msg.removeClass('alertGo'); } });


                if (formUsage == 'new') {
                    changeRequestViewModel.SetChangeRequest(new ChangeRequestModel());
                    CRHelper.SetEditors('new');
                } else {
                    changeRequestViewModel.SetChangeRequest(new ChangeRequestModel(updatedModel));
                    CRHelper.SetEditors('edit');
                }
                if ((formUsage == 'editState' || formUsage == 'edit') && updatedModel.activeStateId === 8)
                    $('#approvedByItems').toggle();
                if (formUsage === 'execute' || (formUsage === 'editState' && updatedModel.activeStateName == 'Approved')) {
                    $('#divExecuted').toggle();
                    $('#divChangeState').hide();
                }
                try {
                    $('#dtpDeadlineRequested').datepicker();
                    $('#dtpDeadlineRequested').datepicker('refresh');

                } catch (e) {
                    $('#dtpDeadlineRequested').datepicker('destroy');
                    $('#dtpDeadlineRequested').datepicker();

                }
                if (transition == "Delete Request") {
                    $('.submitter').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('#divSubmitButtons #buttonSet').toggle();
                    $('#divSubmitButtons #returnLink').toggle();
                    $('#formFields').prop('disabled', true);
                }
                if (updatedModel.activeStateName == 'Executed' || updatedModel.activeStateName == 'Deleted' || updatedModel.activeStateName == 'Approved') {
                    $('#formFields').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('.editor').unbind('dblclick');
                    $('#divSubmitButtons #buttonSet').toggle();
                    $('#divSubmitButtons #returnLink').toggle();
                }
            },
            function (request, status, error) {
                //update message text
                var $msg = $("[id*='StatusMessage']");
                var updateMessage = formUsage == 'execute' ? 'executing' : (formUsage == 'new' ? 'saving' : 'updating');
                $msg.html('Failure ' + updateMessage + ': ' + error);
                $msg.addClass('alertStop').show().fadeOut({ duration: 8000, easing: 'easeInQuint', complete: function () { $msg.removeClass('alertStop'); } });
            },
            function () {
                if (pwChooser)
                    pwChooser.selectedPW([]);

                //hide spinny
            }
        );
        utils.tokenizedAjax(ajax);

    } else {
        ko.validation.group(self.ChangeRequest()).showAllMessages();
        var $msg = $("[id*='StatusMessage']");

        $msg.html('Check your entries and try again')
            .addClass('alertCaution')
            .show()
            .fadeOut({
                duration: 2000,
                easing: 'easeInQuint',
                complete: function () {
                    $msg.removeClass('alertCaution');
                }
            });

    }
}
```

And then here is where I declare the observables on the model - all pretty straightforward:

```
self.description = ko.observable(crData.description || '');
self.domain = ko.observable(crData.domain || '');
self.id = crData.id || 0;
self.impact = ko.observable(crData.impact || '');
self.includesPolicyWaiver = ko.observable(crData.includesPolicyWaiver || false);
self.justification = ko.observable(crData.justification || '');
self.priority = ko.observable(crData.priority || '');
self.scope = ko.observable(crData.scope || '');
self.securityClassification = ko.observable(crData.securityClassification || '');
self.title = ko.observable(crData.title || 'New Change Request');
self.validationProcess = ko.observable(crData.validationProcess || '');
```

I've triple-checked the code and there is nowhere else that the values behind these two form fields are being explicitly changed.  This looks to me like a global-type value is getting toggled then not reset or something.

**This is interesting:** The only change I made was the order of the elements in the html.  Doing the same test/submission, now the other fields that are in the 2nd and 4th position are showing the false positive.  The ones that showed it originally validate as expected.
[image]

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Can you also add your markup? I'm wondering how you are applying your knockout bindings.